# Using SED to change all passwords in a password file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Management has an OLD  windows based FTP server. The service on startup will read from config files on the C:\ drive and load up the parameters it reads from those files (such as GUI size, ports, gateway, usernames, passwords etc etc)

They have over 1100 users in this server, and they want me to change ALL THE PASSWORDS FOR EVER USER.

The config files is just a bunch of values here is an example:

```
[firewall-captures]
UniqueID=JVpFoXad
Login=firewall
Pass=ltPA8PIB
```

Each "Login=" is unique. Is there a way to change all the passwords and then record the username and the new password into a separate file?

I was thinking to do it with SED but i'm not sure about the logic behind it all.

Any help would be most appreciated. Thank you all in advance

Comment: Change them all to what?

Comment: `s/Pass=.*/Pass=newpass/`

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166) (ignore if you're not asking about hw). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Does the config file store the clear-text password, or does it store some kind of cryptographic hash of the password?

Comment: `sed` won't be able to use a different replacement password for each user. You need something like `awk` or `perl` for that, so it can calculate different passwords.

Comment: Hi i was thinking to change them all to random letters and numbers.

Comment: The text file is NOT encrypted. The passwords are all clear text.

Comment: So SED will not be the answer. I will turn my attention to perl and try research a solution

Comment: Alternatively, with AWK, a starting point could be http://muzso.hu/2012/07/21/how-to-generate-random-text-using-an-awk-script ; to dig further in documentation : http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html

Comment: thank you for all the comments. this is helping me focus on what commands or languages would be best to utilize in order to come up with a solution. 

I will check into that muzso.hu site right now